Moment Generating Function of a Product of Random Variables
Suppose $X,Y$ are independent random variables, with respective moment generating functions (MGFs) $M_X(t)$ and $M_Y(t)$. It is known that the MGF of $XY$ is given by
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{txy}f_X(x)f_Y(y) \ \text{d}x \ \text{d}y,
$$
where $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are the respective pdfs of $X$ and $Y$. How does one prove the above formula given the definition $M_{XY}(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{tXY})$? I suppose one could define $Z= XY$, obtain a double integral using the formula for $f_Z(z)$ and conduct a suitable change of variables $z \mapsto xy$. But I'm not sure how to rigorously justify the manipulations.
Edit: As per the accepted answer, this is clear once we use the fact that $X,Y$ being independent implies that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) \ f_Y(y)$. More generally, under the assumption of independence, for a function $h(x,y)$, we have that $\mathbb{E}(h(X,Y)) := \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x,y) \ f_X(x) \ f_Y(y)$.

@Henry indeed, edited and fixed.

It is just using independence to say $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ and so
$$M_{XY}(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{tXY})\\=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{txy}f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ \text{d}x \ \text{d}y\\=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{txy}f_X(x)f_Y(y) \ \text{d}x \ \text{d}y$$

Ah yes, I should have used the independence from the outset, as per the second line. Thanks!
